# GKVoiceChat not connecting nor sending voice data on GameCenter Match

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

I'm trying to set up voice-chat on a game I'm developing for iOS, it successfully creates the match, but when I try to set up the voice-chat it does nothing, what am I doing wrong? It runs without throwing errors. Here's the code I'm using to make the voice-chat.

```
- (void)establishVoice
{
    if (![GKVoiceChat isVoIPAllowed])
        return;

    if (![self establishPlayAndRecordAudioSession])
        return;

    NSLog(@"Did stablish voice chat");

    chat = [match voiceChatWithName:@"GeneralChat"];
    [chat start]; // stop with [chat end];
    chat.active = YES; // disable mic by setting to NO
    chat.volume = 1.0f; // adjust as needed.

    chat.playerStateUpdateHandler = ^(NSString *playerID, GKVoiceChatPlayerState state) {
        switch (state)
        {
            case GKVoiceChatPlayerSpeaking:
                // Highlight player's picture
                NSLog(@"Speaking");
                break;
            case GKVoiceChatPlayerSilent:
                // Dim player's picture
                NSLog(@"Silent");
                break;
            case GKVoiceChatPlayerConnected:
                // Show player name/picture
                NSLog(@"Voice connected");
                break;
            case GKVoiceChatPlayerDisconnected:
                // Hide player name/picture
                NSLog(@"Voice disconnected");
                break;
        } };
}
```

Where establishPlayAndRecordAudioSession is:

```
- (BOOL) establishPlayAndRecordAudioSession
{
    NSLog(@"Establishing Audio Session");
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    if (!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error setting session category: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        success = [audioSession setActive: YES error: &error];
        if (success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Audio session is active (play and record)");
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error activating audio session: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

The code successfully logs "Did stablish voice chat", so it does run the code, but when I start talking, it doesn't seem to get the voice nor send it. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? P.S. I'm not getting the GKVoiceChatPlayerConnected fired.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?

Comment: @JIEWANG No, I stopped trying. :(